# Javascript - Parsing long GET request JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am sending a GET request via JS to *https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=API-KEY-HERE* and it works. Although, I have absolutely no idea how to parse the long JSON that pops up. I want to get the title of the first article.

Code:

```
var HttpClient = function () {
   this.get = function (aUrl, aCallback) {
       var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
       anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
           if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
               aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
       }

       anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
       anHttpRequest.send(null);
    }
}
var client = new HttpClient();
client.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=08f3b70e722d46ebab1fdd5b5499f671', function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Edit: I tried using `console.log(response['articles'][0]);` but that returns an error

Comment: @Patrick No I have not. But I am using JS not .NET

Comment: What error does it return?

Comment: @Patrick ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=<your-api-key-here>', function (response) {
    var json = JSON.parse(response);

    console.log(json['articles'][0]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! Although I have to wait to select this answer